# How to make a SUM() with WHERE in HASMANY relationship on laravel? Any help is appreciated

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Good evening friends, I'm having difficulty on get a `SUM` from a `HASMANY` relationship with a condition.

I was trying to do something like this:

```php
$marketPlaces = ModelAccountMarketplace::with(['orders'])
->whereHas('orders', function ($query) use ($dates) {
    $query->selectRaw('SUM(valor_frete) as somaFreteGratis')
          ->whereBetween('datetime', [$dates['dateStart'], $dates['dateEnd']]);
});
```

But when i try to get the value with: `var_dump($marketPlace->somaFreteGratis);`

I get a `null` value. I try to put the where inside the `WITH()` like:

```
$marketPlaces = ModelAccountMarketplace::with(['orders' => function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('SUM(valor_frete) as somaFreteGratis')->where('tipo_frete', 'gratis');
}])
->whereHas('orders', function ($query) use ($dates) {
    $query->whereBetween('datetime', [$dates['dateStart'], $dates['dateEnd']]);
});
```

But in every try i get a null value when i check with:

```php
<?= var_dump($marketPlace->somaFreteGratis); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished using a `withCount` along with a `Closure`

```php
$marketPlaces = ModelAccountMarketplace::withCount([
    'orders as somaFreteGratis' => function ($query) use ($dates) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('sum(valor_frete)')
        ->where('tipo_frete', 'gratis')
        ->whereBetween('datetime', [$dates['dateStart'], $dates['dateEnd']]);
    }
])
->get();
```

Comment: I tryed this too, but for some reason returns 0 when i try to get with $marketPlaces[0]->somaFreteGratis...and there is 2 rows on mysql with valor_frete where tipo_frete = gratis, but thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, return integer 1 for Marketplaces that have orders with tipo_frete =  gratis, but should return a sum of floats values, right?

Comment: This query returns all marketplaces with their someFreteGratis. If you want a particular marketplace, try replacing `->get()` with `->find(id)`. Then you can access directly with `$marketPlaces->somaFreteGratis`